# IMemoryCache Returning False for Cached Value

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, memorycache

I have a .NET 6 application configured as a Windows Service where I am trying to make use of `IMemoryCache` to store temporary access tokens used for API interactions.  I am seeing some really odd behavior in the cache that is resulting in not being able to retrieve values that I have just added in a previous execution.

I have a simple abstraction for `IMemoryCache` called `ITokenCacheService`, which is implemented as such:

```cs
public class TokenCacheService : ITokenCacheService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public TokenCacheService(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public bool TryGetToken(TokenScope scope, out string token)
    {
        return _cache.TryGetValue(scope, out token);
    }

    public void AddTokenToCache(TokenScope scope, string token, int expiresIn)
    {
        _cache.Set(scope, token, TimeSpan.FromTicks(expiresIn));
    }
}
```

The caller of this class is first attempting to `TryGetToken()` to use the cached value, and if that fails, it reaches out to the API to get a new access token and then caches it with `AddTokenToCache()`.  This works well on the first pass, where the cache is expected to be empty and the token is therefore added.  However, on the second pass when the background service runs again, the `IMemoryCache` will fail to retrieve that same value that was just put in the cache.

Debugging this process, I can actually *see my previously cached value in the cache* before calling `TryGetValue`.  Even so, it returns `false` and fails to return the cached value.  Where it gets really strange - not only is it returning `false` for a value that is actually cached, but after `TryGetValue` executes, *that value is then missing from the cache*, even though it was there before the call.  I modified `TryGetToken` in the following way to test this:

```cs
public bool TryGetToken(TokenScope scope, out string token)
{
    // Casting to have access to .Count 
    var cacheImpl = (MemoryCache)_cache; 

    var countBefore = cacheImpl.Count; // Count here is 1

    var result = _cache.TryGetValue(scope, out token); // Result here is false

    var countAfter = cacheImpl.Count; // Count here is 0 ???

    return result;
}
```

I *can* get the token out if I try to retrieve it right after I set it.  I tested this by modifying `AddTokenToCache` just to check the value:

```cs
public void AddTokenToCache(TokenScope scope, string token, int expiresIn)
{
    _cache.Set(scope, token, TimeSpan.FromTicks(expiresIn));

    // Success here will be 'true' and 'test' will contain the token value. 
    var success = _cache.TryGetValue(scope, out var test); 
}
```

The number of ticks being set for this token is 31536000, which amounts to 18 days and 6 hours.  I don't think I'm hitting an expiration window.  I am using the default registration method for the memory cache without any options:

```cs
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

Am I expecting this service to work in a way that it's not designed, or do I need to configure it some way that I'm not doing?  Really not sure what I'm missing here.  The value is clearly there in the cache when I come back around on the second pass, but `TryGetValue()` is failing and seems to be *removing* it from the cache.

Comment: "*The number of ticks being set for this token is 31536000, which amounts to 18 days and 6 hours*" -- No it doesn't. That's about 3.1 seconds. [See here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iP4tUz). 18 days and 6 hours is a whopping 15768000000000 ticks

Comment: The memory cache uses a WeakReference. The object has been garbage collected and the cache notices that when trying to access the value. It then removes the WeakReference of the garbage collected value. Does that sound plausible?

Comment: I think it's more plausible that the item has expired, and it's only removed from the cache when someone tries to fetch something. `IMemberCache` doesn't keep weak references -- it holds only the cached items strongly

Comment: @canton7: "The default implementation of IMemoryCache uses WeakReference." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0, but yeah, the 3.1 second thing is definitely wrong.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Interesting. I was going through the implementation, and didn't find any. MemoryCache [owns a `CoherentState`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs,97e3fd5830ecd43d,references) which has a [dictionary of `CacheEntry`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs,c3850bb74df99690,references) and each entry [owns its value](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/CacheEntry.cs,aed3b2bfd2bfd0db,references)

Comment: @canton7 Okay, maybe MSDN documentation was not updated. Thanks.

Comment: @canton7 Yikes, you're absolutely right, that's a silly mistake on my part.  I used an online tick calculator for that assumption instead of testing it myself in .NET.  My mistake!  I'll try again with seconds and make sure it works as expected.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: "Tick" is just the speed at which some clock ticks at -- its duration depends on the clock. .NET uses a definition of a "Tick" which is a 10,000th of a millisecond, i.e. 100ns -- they're really small. So if you're dealing with .NET ticks, any number which isn't massive is a red flag: the fact that "31536000" is only 8 digits stood out straight away

Comment: @canton7 Got it, that makes sense.  This is one of my first times working directly with ticks, so I wasn't aware of the massive potential difference between sources there.  Appreciate the insight!

Comment: @canton7 Unsurprisingly, that was exactly it.  I feel pretty dumb!  Please feel free to add an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The number of ticks being set for this token is 31536000, which amounts to 18 days and 6 hours

31536000 ticks is about 3.1 seconds, which is probably the cause of what you're seeing. `MemoryCache` will only go looking for entries to evict when you interact with it. The fact that your entry is disappearing as soon as you try to query it is consistent with that entry expiring, and the `MemoryCache` only noticing at that point.

18 days and 6 hours is a whopping 15768000000000 ticks.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, the problem was entirely with my understanding of ticks (that is to say, using an online calculator to find that duration instead of testing it myself in .NET).  Once I switched to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds()` using the exact same integer value, it works flawlessly.  Slightly embarrassed, though I greatly appreciate you pointing it out